# Button not setting theme when selected in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm designing an application using C# and WPF in the MVVM style. I have a button with a custom style so it displays a black border when focused. The issue I'm experiencing is that I have a requirement that the button must be focused when the form loads, but when I do this it isn't applying the style.

I've tried using `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Button}"` in the view, and `Button.focus()` and `Keyboard.Focus(Button)` in the code behind in both the form load event and the button load event, but it looks like its just focusing the button without applying the style.

Button Style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}"
           x:Key="CustomNegativeButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2.25"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:SquareRadisButton}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 5"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:SquareRadisButton}">
                    <customControls:SquareRadisButton Style="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                                                      Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"
                                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      x:Name="SquareRadisButton">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                       Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                       x:Name="ButtonText"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding IconGlyph}"
                                       FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                       x:Name="ButtonIcon"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </customControls:SquareRadisButton>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IconGlyph" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsNegativeButton" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SquareRadisButton" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource CustomNegativeButtonStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class OkCancelDialogView
    {
        public OkCancelDialogView()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           
        }

        private void OkCancelDialogView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void CancelButton_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CancelButton.Focus();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<dialog:BaseMetroDialog x:Class="Wris.Modules.Referral.UI.View.Dialog.OkCancelDialogView"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Wris.Modules.Referral.UI.Controls"
                        Loaded="OkCancelDialogView_OnLoaded"
                        Title="{Binding DialogOptions.Title}">
    <dialog:BaseMetroDialog.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
    </dialog:BaseMetroDialog.InputBindings>

    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DialogOptions.Message}"
                   FontSize="15"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="10">

            <controls:SquareRadisButton Text="{Binding DialogOptions.AffirmativeButtonText}"
                                        Command="{Binding OkCommand}"
                                        TabIndex="1"
                                        MinWidth="80"/>

            <controls:SquareRadisButton Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                                        IsNegativeButton="True"
                                        TabIndex="0"
                                        Text="{Binding DialogOptions.NegativeButtonText}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding DialogOptions.NegativeButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                        MinWidth="80"
                                        x:Name="CancelButton"
                                        Loaded="CancelButton_OnLoaded"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</dialog:BaseMetroDialog>
```

Comment: From what I see the `CustomNegativeButtonStyle` is in fact applied nowhere. Either assign it to your buttons via the `Style` property or make it an implicit style by omitting the key if you want to apply the style to all buttons in scope.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have a parent style which sets the style to CustomNegativeButton if the property `"IsNegativeButton="True""` like it is above. I'll edit the question to include this style as well

Comment: @Ben: Does the `Focus()` method return `true`? Did you try with the `Keyboard.Focus` method? There is a difference between logical and keyboard focus.

Comment: Yes, its returning true, it looks like the button is in focus, but its not applying a style until either the user clicks on it or tabs to it. Ive tried using keyboard.focus as well but i cant really see any difference

Comment: Does this code actually run as you've shown it? You seem to be defining a Control Template for SquareRadisButton which includes the SquareRadisButton itself. WPF predictably throws at runtime for me saying it can't define a control in terms of itself.

Comment: Having said that, I made the Control Template contain a regular Button, the trigger and CustomNegativeButtonStyle target that, and a test project works fine. A button with IsNegativeButton set to true gets a black border, one without doesn't. I set the focus through the loaded event as you did above.

Comment: So what we need here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): a test project like the one I've created but that actually shows the problem.

Comment: I can post my code if it helps, but it's not really an answer.

Comment: @RichN Thanks, it looks like the issue is due to the styling. I just created a much simpler style and it seems to work ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the styles applied to the button, I believe the issue is due to the 2 styles being applied to the button. It looks like the CustomNegativeButtonStyle isn't applied until after the window is loaded, so once I moved the triggers over to the original style, the button was becoming focused on the form load.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:SquareRadisButton}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 5"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:SquareRadisButton}">
                    <customControls:SquareRadisButton Style="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                                                      Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"
                                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      x:Name="SquareRadisButton">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                       Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                       x:Name="ButtonText"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding IconGlyph}"
                                       FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                       x:Name="ButtonIcon"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </customControls:SquareRadisButton>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IconGlyph" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsNegativeButton" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SquareRadisButton" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource CustomNegativeButtonStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="SquareRadisButton" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2.25"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="SquareRadisButton" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Button` style your trigger can be simplified to use the `IsFocused` property:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    ...
</Trigger>
```

Since this is a dialog, most likely you don't need to set `Focus` to the `Button`, but need to set it as the default button. This will make it click when the user hits the `Enter` key.

You can do this by setting the `IsDefault` property.

In your style you can also add a `Trigger` for the `IsDefault` property and give it border similar to your focus state.

```
<Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
    ...
</Trigger>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure whats happening with the styling when the window first loads. I just tried out this solution and the button is focusing, but it still isn't applying the styling